# How to highlight entire rows if, value on a cell below is TRUE?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I want to highlight say row 1 if cell C2 contains the value TRUE, then hight row 2 if C3 contains the value True and so on. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use a rule with the formula:

```
=$C2
```

and apply it to all the cells in the worksheet.

[image]